# php - create a dropdown for every series

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a MySQL table and would like to create a number of dropdowns where my raceid = programid.

For example

```
Table MYRACES
ID RACEID PROGRAMID TITLE DISTANCE
1    1        1      MYRACE    5
2    1        1      HISRACE   6
3    1        1      HERRACE   7
4    2        2      THATRACE  8
5    2        2      WHATRACE  9
6    3        3      HRDRACE   10
7    3        3      TUFFRACE  11
```

So in essence using PHP and MySQL I would like to create a separate dropdown for every instance where my raceid = programid and return the title in the dropdown. In the example above I would have 3 separate dropdowns.

So far I have

```
$programs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM myraces WHERE raceid = programid", 'ARRAY_A');
foreach ($programs as $program) {
    echo '<select>';
    echo '<option value="'.$program['$id'].'">'.$program['title'].'</option>';
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about when raceid != programid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *guessing* you want something like this:

```
$programs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM myraces WHERE raceid = programid", 'ARRAY_A');

$grouped = array();
foreach ($programs as $program) {
    $grouped[$program['raceid']][] = $program;
}

foreach ($grouped as $group) {
    echo '<select>';
    foreach ($group as $program) {
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>',
               $program['id'], htmlentities($program['title']));
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: Hey deceze, thanks for the reply. With your code I'm getting only one dropdown instead of 3 but at least it is a step closer. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: To say that I'd need so see your data (`$programs`). I hope you get the idea though and can develop it from here.